# JTA BMT transactions using Hibernate with JBoss only performs database reads and no writes

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I am using BMT JTA transaction using Hibernate in our SOAP web service application.The hibernate reads are working fine but the inserts or update though return without errors but the record in database is not updated or created. In case of updates I receive a successful web service message and in case of inserts I receive the new entity with assigned primary keys.But in the database no such updated or new entity exists. This behaviour was initially observed on Websphere Liberty Profile Server 8.5 so thinking of some issue in websphere we then moved to JBoss App server 7.2. But same behaviour was observed.

I have debugged the code and have seen no errors in the flow. The transactions are committed and hibernate sessions are closed successfully. But upon the web service response return I see this error in JBoss servers console

```
    JBAS010152: APPLICATION ERROR: transaction still active in request with status 0
```

Please note that all reads and write work fine when using Hibernates default JDBC transactions on either of Websphere Liberty or JBoss Server.Also the above error is then not there on both the servers.

My JBoss version is JBoss 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8 and Hibernate version is 4.1.8.Final. My                             **hibernate.properties** file has this for JTA .

```
connection.autocommit=false    
hibernate.default_schema=CLI_MANG    
dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
hibernate.connection.datasource=java:/comp/env/jdbc/ClientManagementDS
hibernate.transaction.jta.platform=
org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform
hibernate.transaction.factory_class=
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransactionFactory
hibernate.current_session_context_class=jta
```

As you can see we are using DB2 as database.My XA datasource is defined in JBoss's standalone.xml that uses JBoss's db2jcc4.jar as its driver.

Any help is appreciated 
Thanks